# javascript what is Object vs Object.prototype when used in Object.create's proto parameter

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to understand the difference between Object and Object.prototype. Because to create an empty object Object.prototype is used. I felt why not Object.

I am creating an object in the following ways.

Method 1:

```
o = Object.create(Object.prototype,{ p : {value: "test"} });
console.log(o.__proto__);
```

result is:

```
Object {__defineGetter__: function, __defineSetter__: function, hasOwnProperty: function, __lookupGetter__: function, __lookupSetter__: function…}
```

and

```
console.log(o)
```

result is

```
Object {p: "test"}
    p : "test"
    __proto__ : Object
        constructor : function Object()
        hasOwnProperty : function hasOwnProperty()
        isPrototypeOf : function isPrototypeOf()
        propertyIsEnumerable : function propertyIsEnumerable()
        toLocaleString : function toLocaleString()
        toString : function toString()
        valueOf : function valueOf()
        __defineGetter__ : function __defineGetter__()
        __defineSetter__ : function __defineSetter__()
        __lookupGetter__ : function __lookupGetter__()
        __lookupSetter__ : function __lookupSetter__()
        get __proto__ : function __proto__()
        set __proto__ : function __proto__()
```

vs

```
o = Object.create(Object,{ p : {value: "test"} });
console.log(o.__proto__);
```

result is:

```
function Object() { [native code] }
```

and:

```
console.log(o)
```

result is:

```
Function {p: "test"}
    p : "test"
    __proto__ : function Object()
        arguments : null
        assign : function assign()
        caller : null
        create : function create()
        defineProperties : function defineProperties()
        defineProperty : function defineProperty()
        entries : function entries()
        freeze : function freeze()
        getOwnPropertyDescriptor : function getOwnPropertyDescriptor()
        getOwnPropertyDescriptors : function getOwnPropertyDescriptors()
        getOwnPropertyNames : function getOwnPropertyNames()
        getOwnPropertySymbols : function getOwnPropertySymbols()
        getPrototypeOf : function getPrototypeOf()
        is : function is()
        isExtensible : function isExtensible()
        isFrozen : function isFrozen()
        isSealed : function isSealed()
        keys : function keys()
        length : 1
        name : "Object"
        preventExtensions : function preventExtensions()
        prototype : Object
        seal : function seal()
        setPrototypeOf : function setPrototypeOf()
        values : function values()
        __proto__ : function ()
        [[FunctionLocation]] : <unknown>
```

In general i found that:

```
o = {};
// is equivalent to:
o = Object.create(Object.prototype);
```

why not

```
o = {};
// is equivalent to:
o = Object.create(Object);
```

Comment: Because `new Object` is equivalent to `Object.create(Object.prototype)`. That's how it works - the constructor function that initialises an instance is not the same thing as the object that the instances inherit from.

Answer (score 3):

Cause `Object` is a function used to build objects:

```
Object instanceof Function
```

So you can also do:

```
const o = new Object();
```

If you have read more about inheritance in javascript, you know that calling a function with `new` actually builds up an object that inherits from the constructor functions `.prototype` property and then calls the constructor with *this* being that object, so the upper line equals:

```
const o = Object.create( Object.prototype );
Object.call( o );
```

If you do

```
Object.create( Object )
```

you will create an object that inherits the constructor function. And i admit that its quite confusing that *Object* is actually a *function*, that inherits therefore from *Function.prototype* that inherits from *Object.prototype* ...

Comment: `Object is actually a function, that inherits therefore from Function.prototype that inherits from Object.prototype` - Are both the objects same in this sentence. Also i tried `Function instanceof Object` it says true.

Comment: @sanotsh yes cause *Function* is a *function* that inherits *Function.prototype* which inherits *Object.prototype*

Answer (score 1):

Using code from  js-calendar.js:

```
function defineProperties(target, props)
{
  '''
  Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
}
return function(Constructor,protoProps, staticProps)
{
   if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype,protoProps)
   if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor,protoProps)
}
```

if `.prototype` is removed in the first line, the the 'object'.constructor is not created, so nothing gets inherited with `new`. Not needed in 2nd line because of 1st.